# Python SNMP with PYSNMP F5 ltm

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp, f5

I'am new in this thing,

When I run the following command:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c public localhost .1.3.6.1.4.1.3375.2.2.5.6.2.1.6
```

in my F5 LTM I get all my nodes, pools and state like this:

```
F5-BIGIP-LOCAL-MIB::ltmPoolMbrStatusEnabledState."/Common/pool-cnv-proc-financeiro-processamento-was-9169"."/Common/HAPP102".9169 = INTEGER: enabled(1)
```

But when I use the same OID by pysnmp I get this:

```
[ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(<ObjectName value object at 0x6373150 tagSet <TagSet object at 0x4ab5190 tags 0:0:6> payload [1.3.6.1.4.1.3375...80.49.48.52.9144]>), <Integer value object at 0x6373050 subtypeSpec <ConstraintsIntersection object at 0x4ab5c90 consts <ValueRangeConstraint object at 0x4a17c90 consts -2147483648, 2147483647>> tagSet <TagSet object at 0x4aabad0 tags 0:0:2> payload [1]>)]
```

My question:

Is there a way to parse this pysnmp response or am I doing something wrong?

Here is the python code:

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *


def walk(host, oid):
    for (errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds) in nextCmd(SnmpEngine(),
                                                                        CommunityData('public'),
                                                                        UdpTransportTarget((host, 161)),
                                                                        ContextData(),
                                                                        ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(oid)),
                                                                        lexicographicMode=False):
        if errorIndication:
            break
        elif errorStatus:
            break

        else:

            for varBind in varBinds:
                print(varBind)


walk('10.10.100.89', '1.3.6.1.4.1.3375.2.2.5.6.2.1.6')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to `.prettyPrint()` the pysnmp objects you get in response:

```
for varBind in varBinds:
    print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))
```

Like shown [in the examples](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/walking-operations.html#walk-whole-mib).

EDIT:

If you want the response variable-bindings to be resolved against a MIB, you need to [load](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/mib-tweaks.html#preload-pysnmp-mibs) that MIB (perhaps, `F5-BIGIP-LOCAL-MIB`) into pysnmp like this:

```
...
ContextData(),
ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(oid)).loadMibs('F5-BIGIP-LOCAL-MIB'),
...
```

Alternatively, if you specify MIB symbols in request (as opposed to specifying OIDs), pysnmp will load up the named MIB automatically.

```
...
ContextData(),
ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('F5-BIGIP-LOCAL-MIB', 'ltmPoolMbrStatusEnabledState')),
...
```

Comment: I did that and i received the following response **SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.3375.2.2.5.6.2.1.6.42.47.67.111.109.109.111.110.47.112.111.111.108.45.112.114.111.100.45.105.98.109.45.115.97.109.101.116.105.109.101.45.97.100.118.97.110.99.101.100.45.56.48.15.47.67.111.109.109.111.110.47.73.67.83.80.49.48.57.80 = 1**

Comment: It worked for me after import the F5-BIGIP-LOCAL-MIB... Thanks for the help. But i dont know why im getting only one line, and not all my entries from LTM bigip.

Comment: Just flip `lexicigraphincMode=True` (which is the default) or start with shorter OID. In the latter case you will get all sub-OIDs within the given prefix.